# Making a calculator in java, how to allow numeric inputs only

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

IM trying to make a calculator using Java/eclipse. How do I make that only numeric values can be typed into the text area? So when i run the application it runs perfectly. All the buttons are functioning perfectly. But I would like to have it only allow number input in the text area.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.TextField;

  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.text.ParseException; 
  import java.util.Scanner;

   public class calculator_gui<reutrn> implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
JPanel Panel = new JPanel (new java.awt.FlowLayout());

JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1,20);
JButton but1= new JButton("1");
JButton but2= new JButton("2");
JButton but3= new JButton("3");
JButton but4= new JButton("4");
JButton but5= new JButton("5");
JButton but6= new JButton("6");
JButton but7= new JButton("7");
JButton but8= new JButton("8");
JButton but9= new JButton("9");
JButton but0= new JButton("0");


JButton butadd= new JButton("+");
JButton butsub= new JButton("-");
JButton butmulti= new JButton("*"); 
JButton butdiv= new JButton("/");
JButton buteq= new JButton("=");
JButton butclear= new JButton("C");

Double number1,number2,result;
int addc=0,subc=0,multic=0,divc=0;



public void gui(){

    Panel.setLayout(FlowLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 285);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     //  frame.setResizable(false);

    frame.add(Panel);
    Panel.setBackground(Color.green);

    Panel.add(text);
    text.setBounds(10, 32, 361, 29);



    Panel.add(but1);
    but1.setBackground(Color.red);
    but1.setBounds(10, 81, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but2);
    but2.setBounds(126, 81, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but3);
    but3.setBounds(225, 81, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but4);
    but4.setBounds(10, 115, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but5);
    but5.setBounds(126, 115, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but6);
    but6.setBounds(225, 115, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but7);
    but7.setBounds(10, 149, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but8);
    but8.setBounds(126, 149, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but9);
    but9.setBounds(225, 149, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(but0);
    but0.setBounds(126, 183, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(butadd);
    butadd.setBounds(324, 81, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(butsub);
    butsub.setBounds(324, 115, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(butmulti);
    butmulti.setBounds(324, 183, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(butdiv);
    butdiv.setBounds(324, 149, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(buteq);
    buteq.setBounds(225, 183, 89, 23);

    Panel.add(butclear);
    butclear.setBounds(10, 183, 89, 23);





    but1.addActionListener(this);
    but2.addActionListener(this);
    but3.addActionListener(this);
    but4.addActionListener(this);
    but5.addActionListener(this);
    but6.addActionListener(this);
    but7.addActionListener(this);
    but8.addActionListener(this);
    but9.addActionListener(this);
    but0.addActionListener(this);
    butadd.addActionListener(this);
    butsub.addActionListener(this);
    butmulti.addActionListener(this);
    butdiv.addActionListener(this);
    buteq.addActionListener(this);
    butclear.addActionListener(this);






}

private LayoutManager FlowLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

  Object source = e.getSource();

  if(source==butclear){

      number1=0.0;
      number2=0.0;
      text.setText(null);

  }


  if(source==but1){  
       text.append("1");        

  }


  if(source==but2){  
       text.append("2");        

  }

  if(source==but3){  
       text.append("3");        

  }

  if(source==but4){  
       text.append("4");        

  }

  if(source==but5){  
       text.append("5");        

  }

  if(source==but6){  
       text.append("6");        

  }

  if(source==but7){  
       text.append("7");        

  }

  if(source==but8){  
       text.append("8");        

  }

  if(source==but9){  
       text.append("9");        

  }

  if(source==but0){  
       text.append("0");        

  }
  if(source==butadd){
      number1=number_reader();
      text.setText("");
      addc=1;
      subc=0;
      multic=0;
      divc=0;


  }

  if(source==butsub){
      number1=number_reader();
      text.setText("");
      addc=0;
      subc=1;
      multic=0;
      divc=0;


  }
  if(source==butmulti){
      number1=number_reader();
      text.setText("");
      addc=0;
      subc=0;
      multic=1;
      divc=0;


  }
  if(source==butdiv){
      number1=number_reader();
      text.setText("");
      addc=0;
      subc=0;
      multic=0;
      divc=1;


  }



  if(source==buteq){

      number2=number_reader();
      if(addc>0){
          result=number1+number2;
          text.setText(Double.toString(result));

      }

  if(subc>0){
      result=number1-number2;
      text.setText(Double.toString(result));          
  }

  if(multic>0){
      result=number1*number2;
      text.setText(Double.toString(result));

  }




    }







     if(divc>0){
      result=number1/number2;
      text.setText(Double.toString(result));

           }


       }




public double number_reader(){
    Double num1;
    String s;
    s=text.getText();
    num1=Double.valueOf(s);

    return  num1;


        }




      }
```

Comment: Dude.... Use OOP... and for loops...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop
There are so many places they would save you so much work...

Comment: Here is an example of a for loop to make life simpler:
http://ideone.com/77iUUI

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do.

- Set an `javax.swing.InputVerifier` on your text area.  This will keep people from tabbing out if they type something illegal.  It probably isn't enough.
- Set a custom `Document` for the `JTextArea` in its constructor.  Use a subclass you write of `PlainDocument`, where you override its `insertText` method and reject non-numbers.  This will take care of both typing and of cut-and-paste.

You will do better in your next attempt if you do not have one giant `actionPerformed` method for all the number and operation buttons.  Instead, give each button a subclass of `AbstractAction`.  The number buttons can share instances of one class.

`JComponent`s, which include `JButton`s, can have client properties, so you can write code like

```
JButton but1= new JButton("1");
but1.setClientProperty("digit", "1");  // Why a string? 
    // Suppose you have a switch to use hexadecimals?
```

and then the action listener, which has access to the pressed button, can just call `getClientProperty("digit")` on it to find out what digit the user has chosen.  For a small investment, you save a lot of repetitious code.

Finally, learn the model-view-controller architecture, or `MVC`.  Don't do your manipulations directly on the text area. Without RFC, you will have many problems adding more operations, or switching to a RPN calculator.

1. Create a Model: This has objects for the accumulator and the new operand.
2. Create a View: The Swing setup.
3. Create a Controller: The objects that do the work.  Your actions should be requests of the controller to do something.  The controller should do it to the model, and then the model or the controller should refresh the view.

Also, your calculator class name is a bit weird. The name `calculator_gui<reutrn>` makes no sense; why a generic?  Why violate Java standards?  Just call it `Calculator`.

## Added

The poster wants me to show how to turn the button creation coe into a loop.  So, replace the ten lines:

```
JButton but1= new JButton("1");
JButton but2= new JButton("2");
JButton but3= new JButton("3");
JButton but4= new JButton("4");
JButton but5= new JButton("5");
JButton but6= new JButton("6");
JButton but7= new JButton("7");
JButton but8= new JButton("8");
JButton but9= new JButton("9");
JButton but0= new JButton("0");
```

into:

```
JButton[] digitButton = new JButton[10];  // digitButton is an arry of JButtons,
                                          // Initialized to nulls.
for(final int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    digitButton[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));  // Convert 0 to "0", etc.
                                                        // Then make a button.  
}
```

Now, give each button its own action listener instead of having the main class have one for all.

Comment: I have only been coding for almost 2 weeks. I do not have a good understanding of the language,, just trying to figure it out .

Comment: also could you show me how to use the document method you mentioned

Comment: Sorry. I tend to be too academic, even though I've been in the commercial world for over 20 years. I did choose a number of obscure techniques. And, in fact there's an easier way. Calculators tend to have one-line displays. In Swing, that's a JTextField, not a JTextArea. And, if you want to restrict the content, you use a JFormattedTextField, which is a subclass. So, instead of your text, you'd use JFormattedTextField display = new JFormattedTextField(0). When you need to change the value, you'd call setValue with an integer on it. This does internally what I suggested with the Document.

Comment: Could you maybe add something on for loops and iteration, even if it's just a link? The button creation code is just... *shudder*...

Comment: Done.  But, you really need to learn Java basics first.  The best calculator exercise I know of, actually, comes from Apple and describes how to use XCode and Interface Builder and Objective-C to create a calculator.  I don't know if you have the inclination to learn all that, but if you did, it would give you a solid grounding.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a condition:

```
if ((text.contains("[a-zA-Z]+") == false){
//error
}

else{
//do your computation.
}
```

or

```
if ((text.contains("[0-9]*") == true){
//your code    
}
```